# How to move particular applications from one iPad to another?

Tags: itunes, ipad, data-synchronization

I would like to install some particular applications, which I have on one iPad, to another iPad (I don't want to copy all applications and copy settings, so iCloud backup will not work here). The same Apple ID is used on both iPads.
I thought that I can do it thru iTunes applications installed on my Macbook. But it doesn't display all applications installed on my first iPad, synchronization also doesn't help.

I understand that I can manually install needed applications on the second iPad, but there about 30 of them.

Comment: In iTunes - Sync both devices. Backup the first. Then the second should have the full app list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both iPads registered with the same AppleID and syncing does not put all of them on both devices try this.

Open the App store and search for the apps that are on the other iPad that you want on this one. In place of a buy/get button should be a cloud with a downward pointing arrow on it. Tap that to install it on that iPad.

If the button says Buy or Get then the App store thinks this iPad is on a different account associated with a different AppleID.